# Evaluate time series by year

Tags: excel, excel-formula, time-series

I have a table with this contents (example here uses quarters instead of months):

```
Time    | Value 
--------+-------
2005.01 | 101
2005.02 | 104
2005.03 | 101
2005.04 | 105
2006.01 | 111
2006.02 | 104
2006.03 | 109
2006.04 | 115
2007.01 | 121
2007.02 | 114
2007.03 | 131
2007.04 | 125
...

2013.01 | 101
2013.02 | 104
2013.03 | 101
2013.04 | 105
```

What I want to do is, seeing graphically how the values change over the course of a year.
I want to see them all in on chart - each year one curve in the chart.

As far as I understand excel/oo.calc I have to split the date into a suitable format to make graphs.

I would like to create something like this:

```
Year | 2005 | 2006 | 2007 | ... | 2013
Quart|      |      |      |     |     
-----+------+------+------+-----+-----
  01 |  101 |  111 |  121 |     |  101
  02 |  104 |  104 |  114 |     |  104
  03 |  101 |  109 |  131 |     |  101
  04 |  105 |  115 |  125 |     |  105
```

But my Excel formula magic is to weak to make this happen. Could you point out solutions how to achieve this. (I prefer formula over macro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract year with `=left(cell, 4)`, quarter with `=right(cell, 2)`, then use pivot chart (placing `year` in `Legend Fields`, `quarter` in `Axis Fields`, and `value` in `Values`).

Alternatively, as suggested by @pnuts, you can use the `Text to Column` feature (under `Data` tab) to separate `Time` into 2 columns (separated by `.`).

Comment: @pnuts, thanks for the suggestion. It's included in the answer.

Comment: This worked. For all of you that do not know much about pivot tables: You can not only filter and select values in them, but mark the value area and create graphs from it (like suggested in the answer). Very helpful.